# How can I make functionality accessible directly from my package (not a module within that package)?

Tags: python, import, package

I'm really interested in creating a package in python. To do so, I watched and read several tutorials but there is always something that doesn't want to work.

**What I'm doing**

I created a folder `package__tutorial` in which I have another folder which corresponds to the name of my package - `mypackage`.

Folder `mypackage` contains two files:

1. `__init__.py` - file which indicates where the package is
2. `functions.py` - file which contains functions to be included into the package

In functions.py have some one basic function:

```
def average(x,y):
    return (x+y)/2
```

To summarize - my file structure is the following

`package__tutorial` containing `mypackage` containing `__init__.py` and `functions.py`.

Now - to load my package I just need to use:

```
from mypackage import functions
```

Then to use function average from this package we just need to use:

```
functions.average(2, 8)
```

However importing a file containing functions it's not so convenient for me. Is there any possibility to make this import in a standard way as to other packages ?

For example -

```
import numpy as np
np.linspace()
```

I would prefer to have exactly the same:

```
import mypackage as mp 
mp.average()
```

Is there any possibility to do so ? To do not import specific file containing functions, but just a package.

**EDIT**

I read the post you have given me, and in `__init__.py` I included:

```
from .functions import *
```

and it solved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: The `__init__.py` does more than just indicate where the files are

Comment: use `__init__.py`

Comment: [What is `__init__.py` for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)

Comment: Specifically, your question is answered at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18979314) on the above-linked question. This is a good question to ask, and I deleted my original comments because it turns out the documentation is not actually as clear about this stuff as I would have expected. It is a good question because, although it is already answered, you have asked it in a new way that is likely to match how others will search for it.